# How to return non-repeating values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d"]
```

I'm looking for function that returns non-repeating element like "c" from the above example as that's the only one without duplicate.

I have searched for an hour but all the results I found online returns:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

which is not what I want.

Example - how to push the single occurring Bond allBond to uniqueBond ?

```js
const bondFilms = [
  { "title" : "Skyfall", "year" : 2012, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$1,108,561,008" },
  { "title" : "Thunderball", "year" : 1965, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$1,014,941,117" },
  { "title" : "Goldfinger", "year" : 1964, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$912,257,512" },
  { "title" : "Live and Let Die", "year" : 1973, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$825,110,761" },
  { "title" : "You Only Live Twice", "year" : 1967, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$756,544,419" },
  { "title" : "The Spy Who Loved Me", "year" : 1977, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$692,713,752" },
  { "title" : "Casino Royale", "year" : 2006, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$669,789,482" },
  { "title" : "Moonraker", "year" : 1979, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$655,872,400" },
  { "title" : "Diamonds Are Forever", "year" : 1971, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$648,514,469" },
  { "title" : "Quantum of Solace", "year" : 2008, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$622,246,378" },
  { "title" : "From Russia with Love", "year" : 1963, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$576,277,964" },
  { "title" : "Die Another Day", "year" : 2002, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$543,639,638" },
  { "title" : "Goldeneye", "year" : 1995, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$529,548,711" },
  { "title" : "On Her Majesty's Secret Service", "year" : 1969, "actor" : "George Lazenby", "gross" : "$505,899,782" },
  { "title" : "The World is Not Enough", "year" : 1999, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$491,617,153" },
  { "title" : "For Your Eyes Only", "year" : 1981, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$486,468,881" },
  { "title" : "Tomorrow Never Dies", "year" : 1997, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$478,946,402" },
  { "title" : "The Man with the Golden Gun", "year" : 1974, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$448,249,281" },
  { "title" : "Dr. No", "year" : 1962, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$440,759,072" },
  { "title" : "Octopussy", "year" : 1983, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$426,244,352" },
  { "title" : "The Living Daylights", "year" : 1987, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$381,088,866" },
  { "title" : "A View to a Kill", "year" : 1985, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$321,172,633" },
  { "title" : "License to Kill", "year" : 1989, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$285,157,191" }
];

let uniqueBond = ""
let allBond = []
for (i = 0; i < bondFilms.length; i++) {
  allBond.push(bondFilms[i].actor)
}
console.log(allBond)
```

[Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates) does not solve it as it only removes duplicates, but I want to keep uniques.

Comment: Since it is array of object, it is better if you write what is your criteria for uniqueness? Is it title or any values or all the values?

Comment: Please don't edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: @mindmaster Nope. I also posted dupes, he wants values that only occur once. Not a list of unique values

Comment: Thanks for all your answers guys. I don't quite understand how it works yet, but I've saved it and will get my JS lecturer to explain when I'm in class tomorrow. Also noted on the edit - didn't mean to invalidate any answers!! My apologies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that if an element occurs only once in the array, its `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` will be the same. So

```
uniqueBond = bondFilms
     .map(film => film.actor)
     .filter((actor, _, actors) => actors.indexOf(actor) === actors.lastIndexOf(actor))
```

Applied to the abc example:

```js
let arr = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d"];

let uniq = arr.filter(x => arr.indexOf(x) === arr.lastIndexOf(x));

console.log(uniq);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```js
var arr = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d"];

let count={};
arr.forEach(x=>{

 if(!count[x]) count[x]=0;
 count[x]++;

})

let result = arr.filter(x=>count[x]===1);
console.log(result)
```

<sub>**Note** since we store counts in object using array value as key and since keys
in JS objects are strings, this code doesn't distinguish between 5 and "5".
That is it will return [1, 2] from an input of say [1, 2, 5, "5"] because it will consider 5 and "5", "same". Other than that, it should be ok.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let uniqueBonds = [...new Set([...allBonds])];
```

Basically with **Set** you will get unique items and you convert them to array with **Spread Operator**.

Answer (score 0):

You can meet the requirement by filtering items that have the same first index and last index:

```js
var arr = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d"];
var uniq = arr.filter((item) => arr.indexOf(item) === arr.lastIndexOf(item));

console.log(uniq)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d"]

const newtest = arr.filter((element, index, array) => {
  const temp = array.filter(x => x === element);
  if(temp.length < 2) {
    return element;
  }
})

console.log('original ---  ', arr);
console.log('final ---  ', newtest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
var arr = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d"]

var counts = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) { return Object.assign(acc, {[curr]: (acc[curr] || 0) + 1})   }, {})

var singleOccurrences = Object.keys(counts).filter(function(k) { return counts[k] === 1})

console.log(singleOccurrences);
```

Explanation:

`var counts = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) { return Object.assign(acc, {[curr]: (acc[curr] || 0) + 1})   }, {})`
 counts the occurrences for each item of the list (returning an object, whose keys are the items - for each key, the value is the count of the occurrences)

`var singleOccurrences = Object.keys(counts).filter(function(k) { return counts[k] === 1})`  iterates over keys in `counts` and apply a filter to the list, preserving only the kyes with exactly one occurrence

I hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf and compare it to lastIndexOf

```js
var result = [1,1,2].filter( ( x, i, array ) => array.indexOf(x) === array.lastIndexOf(x))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` is the best solution. However if you for some unknown reason don't want to do that, here is my contribution with some es6 spread operators and reduce().

```js
let a = ["1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "1"];

const uniqueItems = a.reduce((acc, item, i) => ![...a.slice(0,i), ...a.slice(i+1,a.length)].includes(item) 
  ? acc.concat([item]) 
  : acc , [])

console.log(uniqueItems);
// output: ['2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function to get unique values. It creates a hash for counting the frequency of every element in the arr and returns the unique values with frequency equals to 1

```js
function getUnique(arr){
  var hash = {};
  var uniques = [];
  arr.forEach(ele =>{
    if(hash[ele]){
      hash[ele] +=1
    }
    else{
      hash[ele] = 1;
    }
  });
  
  Object.keys(hash).forEach(key =>{
    if(hash[key]==1){
      uniques.push(key);
    }
  });
 
 return uniques;
 
}
var arr = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d"];
console.log(getUnique(arr));
```